# Make PhpStorm recognize PreCSS (Sass-like) variables in CSS

Tags: css, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm following a tutorial that uses variables in `.css` files using a package called [PreCSS](https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss) (a set of plugins that adds Sass-like functionality) and [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/). The packages are required with gulp.

I have a file called `_variables.css` and when defining variables everything turns red and it says "selector matches unknown element". 
For example:

```
$blue: #0076A3;
```

The code is working though, so I need to get PhpStorm to recognize this code somehow.

But would it work if had used Sass instead? It's the same principle, though, using variables.

In Project Settings - Inspections, SASS/SCSS is activated so I guess it should recognize Sass variables. I don't know if it is because I use this PreCSS package.

Can it be fixed sin some way?

Comment: Until PostCSS (and most popular plugins) is properly supported by IDE, your only option is to associate the `*.css` extension with the language that supports such syntax (Sass in your case) -- it can be done in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`. NOTE: this is IDE-wide setting and will affect all projects and all *.css files.

Comment: On File Types, "CSS files", I can edit "registered patterns" and add wildcards, or if I double click "css files" I can "edit filetype", and "add keyword",  but I don't what I'm supposed to do. How do you associate SASS with CSS?

Comment: What "CSS files"? Screenshots please. It's not standard file type -- you must be doing something wrong or used something else (custom plugin/textmate bundle/etc?) to add it there. By default `*.css` pattern is associated with "Cascading Style Sheet" file type. My suggestion above is to re-associate that pattern with "Sass" file type (or SCSS -- whatever matches your needs). Ideally, instead of working with `.css` files, you better use some custom file extension for that (e.g. `.postcss`) -- this way ordinary CSS files will still be treated correctly in other projects.

Comment: Okay, I just found the "Cascading style sheets" file type (there was also "CSS files" in the list, maybe it was custom added long ago..)Good idea about doing a custom file type! I guess I just add *.scss on "registered patterns" to this file type?

Comment: *"Good idea about doing a custom file type!"* Not file type! I've said "custom **extension**". Custom file type will do nothing for you -- it works other way around. The whole idea of my words above is: add custom file extension to existing file type -- e.g. add `*.postcss` (or `*.precss` if you prefer this) pattern to `Sass` file type. And then rename your `_variables.css` to `_variables.precss`

Comment: Ok, then I understand, I think. I can try and see if it works... maybe preCSS requires the css-extension to work when doing @import and stuff..

Comment: PostCSS and PreCSS are not supported in WebStorm. Please vote for a related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16601

Comment: You can use postCSS PHPStorm plugin:https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8578?pr=phpStorm

Answer (score 0):

Since September 2016 you can use the EAP version 2016.3 for PostCSS support.

Download-Link:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

More info:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8578?pr=phpStorm

Comment: The PostCSS plugin does not support postcss-variables yet.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post here is some follow up for users who come across it.

**TLDR:** use [postcss-preset-env](https://preset-env.cssdb.org) or [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)

JetBrains products now have a [PostCSS plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8578-postcss-support) which can be installed. It only supports a small subset of PostCSS plugins, which given that there an infinite number this makes sense.

> The following PostCSS plugins are supported:
>
> - postcss-custom-properties
> - postcss-apply
> - postcss-custom-media
> - postcss-media-minmax
> - postcss-custom-selectors
> - postcss-nesting
> - postcss-nested

Fortunately, the prolific [Jonathan Neal](https://github.com/jonathantneal) who wrote PreCSS is the major contributor to [postcss-preset-env](https://preset-env.cssdb.org) which uses all of these plugins plus current and upcoming W3C specifications. CSS Variables should be used as per the W3C spec `var(--your-var-name)` rather than custom variable syntax.

**FYI:** postcss-preset-env has superseded [cssnext](https://moox.io/blog/deprecating-cssnext/) which is now deprecated due to the author favouring [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) and [CSS-in-JS](http://cssinjs.org/?v=v9.8.7).